# Nameservers to same IP in Direct Admin

Tags: nameserver

I have a very simple server with just a few personal domains, but it runs with DirectAdmin which I don't want to change.

This server has 2 IP's, 1 for NS1 and 1 for NS2. Now I want to have 1 IP back, they point to the same server anyway.

Is there a way to have NS1 and NS2 point to the same IP, so one IP opens up?

If this is not possible, what are the consequences of running with only 1 NS?

Comment: When you say you want the IP back, do you want to use it again on same server or different one?

Comment: No I want to use it on a different server.

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both NS can point to the same IP, but not all registrars are allowed. One NS for TLD probably not happen.

[RFC 2182](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2182.html):

> 5. How many secondaries?
>
>    The DNS specification and domain name registration rules require at
>      least two servers for every zone.  That is, usually, the primary and
>      one secondary.  While two, carefully placed, are often sufficient,
>      occasions where two are insufficient are frequent enough that we
>      advise the use of more than two listed servers.  Various problems can
>      cause a server to be unavailable for extended periods - during such a
>      period, a zone with only two listed servers is actually running with
>      just one.  Since any server may occasionally be unavailable, for all
>      kinds of reasons, this zone is likely, at times, to have no
>      functional servers at all.